# How do you translate a rackup invocation to a self-contained script?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm trying to make a gem out of an app that did:

```
 spawn("rackup", "--port", PORT.to_s, "--server", "thin", "-E", "development", File.expand_path("../server.ru", __FILE__))
```

If I use this in the gem I get a `LoadError` for `thin` (after packaging it and installing it) (`thin` is in my gemspec but I guess the error has to do with the spawning of the rackup executable, which is not part of the gem's bundle).

Replacing:

```
run app
```

with

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run app
```

in the `server.ru` file will start the server, but I need to set the parameters too.

I tentatively tried:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV']='development'
Rack::Handler::Thin.run app, host: 'localhost', port: PORT.to_s
```

to no avail. What is the recipe for translating parameterized `rackup` invocations to executable `*.ru` files with explicit handlers?

Answer (score 0):

`Rack::Handler::Thin` had a `valid_options` method.
None of those keys worked, nor did various combinations.
The `SERVER_PORT` and `SERVER_HOST` env variables didn't work either.

I endend up running the `thin` executable with the `*.ru` file as an argument and **that did it**.

It may well be that the things I've tried would've worked with some handler other than Thin (i.e., thin might be a crappy rack citizen). I don't know or care. Just needed to get this working. I will, of course, appreciate (upvote/accept) answers that shed more light on this